# Return start Node at lest if no matchs are found

Tags: neo4j, cypher

What is the right query which return start node at least if matches are not found

START n=node(0) MATCH n-[r*]-> m  return n, m;

This query return result along with start node if there match node found, however if my graph is empty it is not returning start node at lest.

Here if MATCH condition not found any result return 0 result. I expect at least start node.

Answer (score 0):

The `*` quantifier is a shortcut for `*1..` (aka 1 to infinity). If you use `*0..` a path of length 0 is also a valid match, so it contains just the start node:

```
START n=node(0) MATCH n-[r*0..]-> m return n, m;
```